# My two-dimensional array is getting filled with zeros instead of random numbers

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I created a two-dimensional array that I want to fill with random digits within a range up to 10. However, the printed end-result ends up being all zeros. I cannot see what is wrong with my code, and I am certain everything is correct. I searched for similar issues here at Stack Overflow, but cannot find a problem that is similar to mine. My code is below:

```
int [][] array = new int [3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
{   array[i][j] = ( (int) Math.random() * 10 );  
System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");  } 
System.out.println(" ");     }
```

Comment: *Casting* has higher precedence than multiplication making `(int) Math.random() * 10` be executed as it was written `((int) Math.random()) * 10` (see the problem here? `Math.random()` returns values in range `[0...1)` where `1` is excluded). You want `(int) (Math.random() * 10)`

Comment: @Pshemo, I actually tried doing exactly as you did, prior to posting on Stack Overflow, but it didn't work :(

Comment: @AnneBailly try the full code I posted below it worked for me.

Comment: @AnneBailly "...but it didn't work" could you include code you tried? As Omarito shown in his answer this solution should work fine.

Comment: @Pshemo, actually...the code did indeed work.What I had tried was slightly different, so the code both you and Omarito provided does indeed work as it should :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple. Its just your casting `Math.random()` to *int* and not the result of the multiplication. 
 
Your original code have this line :

```
array[i][j] = ( (int) Math.random() * 10 );
```

which will cast `Math.random()` to `int` while `Math.random()` return *double* in the interval *[0..1]*. The result of the cast to `int` will be then 0.
What you should do instead is casting the multiplication of `Math.random()` with 10:

```
array[i][j] = ( (int) (Math.random() * 10) );
```

Here is the full working code :

```
public class RandomArray{
     public static void main(String []args){
        int [][] array = new int [3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){   
                array[i][j] = ( (int) (Math.random() * 10) );  
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");  
            } 
            System.out.println(" ");    
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: that worked, and I actually learned something new and useful about Java!